# Fix nodes location with respect to canvas boundaries

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I am trying to use Vis.js in a flowchart like scenario.

I am getting information of the flowchart from the database and want to use Vis.js to help me lay out the flowchart nodes propely.

However, I want the START node and END node to always be at the center of left edge and center of right edge of the container.

I can't seem to figure out the options to do so.

My code so far is in this pen:

```
 var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
 var nodes = [];
 var edges = [];
 nodes.push({
   id: 1,
   label: "START",
   shape: "box",
   fixed: {
     x: true,
     y: true,
   },
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
 });
 nodes.push({
   id: 2,
   label: "test node 2"
 });
 nodes.push({
   id: 3,
   label: "test node 3"
 });
 nodes.push({
   id: 4,
   label: "test node 4\n Second line"
 });
 nodes.push({
   id: 99,
   label: "END",
   fixed: true,
   shape: "box",
 });
 edges.push({
   from: 1,
   to: 2,
   label: 'text'

 });
 edges.push({
   from: 1,
   to: 3
 });

 edges.push({
   from: 3,
   to: 99
 });
 edges.push({
   from: 2,
   to: 4
 });
 edges.push({
   from: 4,
   to: 99
 });
 edges.push({
   from: 3,
   to: 4
 });
 var data = {
   nodes: nodes,
   edges: edges
 };
 var options = {
   physics: {
     enabled: true,
     stabilization: true,
     barnesHut: {
       avoidOverlap: 1
     },
   },
   edges: {
     arrows: {
       to: {
         enabled: true,
         scaleFactor: 1
       },
       middle: {
         enabled: false,
         scaleFactor: 1
       },
       from: {
         enabled: false,
         scaleFactor: 1
       }
     },

   }

 };
 var timeline = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwdGvP

How do I get the location of START and END nodes fixed with respect to the container and then let VIS JS take care of the rest of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
fixed: {
  x: true,
  y: true
}
```

to your nodes.

Comment: I have already done that , my question is how to specify the co ordinates so that the node appears on those  fixed co ordinate location on the canvas.

Comment: So you alway want to have them fixed at left and right edge even if you are moving/zooming the canvas?

Comment: yes  . i am creating a flowchart .. it doesnt make sense to have the start and end nods floating around in the middle of the page